# Detect if someone is noclipping or flying(Roblox Lua)

Tags: lua, roblox

So, I am making a game that is highly sensitive to hackers and if someone did hack it, it would be completely ruined. Is there any possible way to detect if someone is flying/noclipping and kick them using Roblox Lua scripts??

Comment: if you expect anything more than "yes" you should invest more effort into your post. share some code. show what you have tried. for example it is trivial to detect if someone is flying. you can solve this with a few minutes of websearch

Comment: I'm sorry sir, I have tried to search on the web for a possible answer with only the results of how to make a fly script.

Comment: @Kwallcoder you question is receiving down vote because it is low quality. if you look at the first comment, 3 people other than Piglet believe he has made a good point. 2 of those people likely downvoted your question. your question is lacking focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have not made anything in roblox before, so this might not work

one way to detect flying is the check the y of the player:

```
if y > 100 then -- y can be replaced with other variables, and i recommend you change 100 to another number
    -- ban
end
```

you can also apply this to x and z.
this solution however only works if the player flies to a certain point, so you might have to get creative, i'll edit this answer when i finish reading the documentation

another way is by making an object out of bounds, when the player collides with this object it bans them.

that is all i can think of, let me know if you have any problems!

Comment: so if I climb a ladder or stair I'll be banned too because my y coordinate is too high? why not check if the HumanoidState is Flying? https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/enum/HumanoidStateType

Comment: the first solution that i provided assumed the game had no ladders or stairs, making the invisible object will solve the problem the first solution had (however the first solution is much quicker). thanks for providing a link to HumanoidState!

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer on the devforums, but if a player is noclipping, they have no hitbox, meaning you can raycast from the HumanoidRootPart, and if that ray can't see the player, then they are noclipping however, some false positives may occur with laggy players so beware.
Anway the devforums are a better place to get your answer so go there instead.